# what cause sfp not inserted in a cisco 5596?

Tags: cisco

what cause sfp not inserted in a  cisco 5596? I have already swapped sfp to verify not a bad sfp. when I do a sh transciever command it shows tansceiver present.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a 1G SFP and not a 10G SFP+?  You need to set the speed for the 55xx switches to step down to 1G speeds.

Otherwise it could be a non-Cisco SFP and you need to enable support for it.